# Show that $ |\operatorname{det}(x, y)| \leq|x|^{s}|y|^{t}|x-y|^{r} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, determinant

Show that for any $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and for any $r, s, t \in[0,1]$ with $r+s+t=2$ we have
$$
|\operatorname{det}(x, y)| \leq|x|^{s}|y|^{t}|x-y|^{r}
$$
Here $(x, y)$ represents the $2 \times 2$ matrix with vectors $x$ and $y$ as columns.

Hint: If you replace $y$ by $y-x \ldots$.

I don't know how to proceed, I guessed that replacing $y$ by $y-x$ will come at the end because of the symmetricity of $|y|^{t}$ and $|x-y|^{r}$ but I am not seeing any point to start. It is supposed to be a real analysis/calculus question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $D = |\det(x, y)|$. The estimate
$$
D \le |x| |y|
$$
follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:
$$
|D| = |x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1| \le |x_1|| y_2| + |x_2|| y_1| \le \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2} \sqrt{y_2^2+y_1^2} = |x| |y| \, .
$$
Substituting $x$ or $y$ by $x-y$ does not change the absolute value of the determinant, so that also
$$
D \le |x| |x-y| \, ,\\
D \le |x-y| |y| \, .
$$
Now we can exponentiate these three inequalities with suitable exponents and multiply them to get the desired result:
$$
 D = D^{1-r} D^{1-t} D^{1-s} \le \bigl( |x| |y|\bigr)^{1-r}  \bigl( |x| |x-y|\bigr)^{1-t} \bigl( |x-y| |y|\bigr)^{1-s} = |x|^s |y|^t |x-y|^r \, .
$$

Comment: Wow! One question: Isn't $D=\det(x,y)=\det 
    \begin{pmatrix}
    x_1 & y_1 \\
    x_2 & y_2 
    \end{pmatrix}
=x_1y_2-x_2y_1$? Then why is $D\leq |x||y|$?

Comment: @Ri-Li: I have added the calculation.